# Rails: Passing User state between many controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a simple Rails application with multiple controllers and I want to pass User state around between many different controllers and views.

The user can have a organization and a project.

I want to pass `current_org` and `current_project` across all my controllers/views, which are the objects for the current organization and the current project.

What's the best way to do this? I want to reduce the need to make a database call on every page load. Is it possible to persist these in `current_user` so that I can call `current_user.current_project`?

Comment: current_user is accesible everywhere. For the rest, You can use helpers

Answer (score 3):

As web requests are stateless at heart, each new page render will require re-fetching data from somewhere. Your `current_user` method is itself making a database call behind the scenes (assuming a stock Devise setup) to load the user on each page load. Similarly, while you can define a helper or module to share `current_org` and `current_project` values, like Ritaful pointed out, they will need to make database calls to fetch their values.

Or at least, that's the typical Rails answer. You do have some other options. The first is to use the session storage to store the objects, through either native Ruby marshaling (a dangerous path, as the legacy systems I work with have shown) or through perhaps JSON serialization:

```rb
# marshalling
def current_org
  # this will break if your organization object contains a proc, and 
  # can risk exploding your session storage if your object gets large
  session[:current_org] ||= current_user.organization
end

# serialization
def current_org
  session[:current_org] ||= current_user.organization.to_json
end
```

However, the JSON object won't be an ActiveRecord model, so your code will have to adapt. You can technically make it a record through `#from_json`, but your relations won't work like you expect and in general you'd be straying too far into the woods at that point.

Overall, I would avoid trying to prematurely optimize your database calls. A schema with proper indices can perform index lookups very quickly, so these lookups are unlikely to cause a problem. If you do start seeing issues, I'd start with looking into eager loading to reduce the number of queries made per page load, but not try too hard to eliminate them. As you scale, you can add layers of caching and dig into optimizations to further reduce database impact.

Answer (score 1):

You can create two methods in your `ApplicationHelper`

```
def current_project
  current_user.current_project
end

def current_org
  current_user.current_org
end
```

These will be available to all controllers and views.

For more information, check "[How to Use Rails Helpers (Complete Guide)](https://www.rubyguides.com/2020/01/rails-helpers/)".

Answer (score 0):

What about the session?  It's probably the easiest way.  I remember I did something like this:

1. When use logs in assign that id to `session[:current_user_id]`
2. Whenever a user navigates to another page have a private method that looks something like this:

```
def setup(id)
    @user = User.find(id)
end
```

3. Run that method in a before_action method like this:

```
before_action do 
   setup(session[:current_session_id])
end
```